# Unclosed group near index 14

Tags: java, regex

I get error on this line:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(word + "\\(.*\\)");
```

It says:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 14
```

I know this error is when you leave not escaped special characters but I dont see any there..

**FULL CODE:**

```
                StyleConstants.setItalic(set, true);
                    for (String word : code.split("\\s")) {
                        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(word + "\\(.*\\)");
                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
                        while (matcher.find()) {
                            doc.setCharacterAttributes(matcher.start(), word.length(), set, true);
                        }
                    }
```

code is a string. It explodes code and checks every word. If word matches, colors it

Comment: What is the value of `word` - if it has a regexp character in it that too has to be escaped.

Comment: So and where do you tell us now the content of `word`?

Comment: How can I know content of word? Word is part of string code. If string is "Some large string" then loop will go through "some", "large" and "string" and check each. If code will be "some function()" then it should go through "some" and "function()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("abcd" + "\\(.*\\)");
log.debug("RegEx: " + pattern);
```

And that worked fine:

```
RegEx: abcd\(.*\)
```

I can only assume that you have some unescaped characters in `word`.

If you don't know the value of `word` at compile time then build the pattern and log it before calling the `compile()` method:

```
String regex = word + "\\(.*\\)";
System.out.println("Regex: \"" + regex + "\"");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

Comment: But how can I know if word contains some uneascaped characters? Should I check every word before compiling it? No other option?

Comment: Yes, you have to scan every word before compiling it.  `The compile()` doesn't know what is and what is a word - it see the whole thing as one regex pattern that must obay regex syntax.